# Ubuntu 16.04: E: Package 'libqwt6' has no installation candidate

Tags: 16.04

I have already tried sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade. It didn't work. 
I tried to install the package by sudo apt install libqwt, but I get the same error.

Any type of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Be careful & accurate with commands as `&&` and `&` have different meanings (and will likely have different results). The package 'libqwt6' is for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (amd64, armhf, i38...) and isn't for 16.04 LTS (due changes, its purpose is provided by libqwt6abi1)  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqwt6

Answer (score 2):

`libqwt6` is only available in the repositories through Trusty.  Since Trusty, there's been multiple packages produced by `qwt`'s source package:

> - libqwt-dev: Qt widgets library for technical applications (development, qt4)
> - libqwt-dev-dbgsym: debug symbols for package libqwt-dev
> - libqwt-doc: Qt widgets library for technical applications (documentation)
> - libqwt-headers: Qt widgets library for technical applications (header files)
> - libqwt-qt5-6: Qt widgets library for technical applications (runtime, qt5)
> - libqwt-qt5-6-dbgsym: debug symbols for package libqwt-qt5-6
> - libqwt-qt5-dev: Qt widgets library for technical applications (development, qt5)
> - libqwt-qt5-dev-dbgsym: debug symbols for libqwt-qt5-dev
> - libqwt6abi1: Qt widgets library for technical applications (runtime, qt4)
> - libqwt6abi1-dbgsym: debug symbols for libqwt6abi1
> - libqwtmathml-dev: Text Engine for Qwt (development, qt4)
> - libqwtmathml-qt5-6: Text Engine for Qwt (runtime, qt5)
> - libqwtmathml-qt5-6-dbgsym: debug symbols for package libqwtmathml-qt5-6
> - libqwtmathml-qt5-dev: Text Engine for Qwt (development, qt5)
> - libqwtmathml6abi1: Text Engine for Qwt (runtime, qt4)
> - libqwtmathml6abi1-dbgsym: debug symbols for libqwtmathml6abi1

It is likely that one of *these* packages are what you need, but it looks like there's different Qt version dependencies for each.  Identify the one you need, and install *that* one specifically.

Comment: I am not able to install any of dbgsym  packages, I am getting the "E: Unable to locate package libqwt-dev-dbgsym" error for each of them. I installed all other packages, yet I have the same issue (E: Package 'libqwt6' has no installation candidate).

Comment: I have installed the packages, I am still getting the same error. Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'libncurses-dev'
Package libqwt6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libqwt6' has no installation candidate

Comment: @user792549 It *sounds* like you need to run `sudo apt-get update` among other things.  Try running `sudo apt-get update` and then seeing if you can then get package candidates for installation.  (I've only ever seen this on a system that hasn't updated recently)